# nodejs Mysql sum() return json as function? please check to understand me

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this array in Node.JS as a result of the MySQL query.

```
 let GetTotalMoney = "SELECT sum(total) FROM request WHERE is_completed = 1";
        connections.query(GetTotalMoney, function(err, result, fields){

            console.log(result) // result is [{ "sum(total)": "1091.75" }]
        })
```

It Gives a weird JSON as cuz I never seen it before the result is [{ "sum(total)": "1091.75" }]

How can i parse it or get the value inside it

Comment: Change `SELECT sum(total) FROM request WHERE is_completed = 1` to `SELECT sum(total) AS TotalMoney FROM request WHERE is_completed = 1`  and you probably will get next result: `[{ "TotalMoney": "1091.75" }]`

Comment: Thank you so much that's really what I was needing Cuz I'm new in MySQL thank you !!!

Comment: The thing that i added to the query is commonly know as an [alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) or [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)